# How to save FormView file in Odoo 10 after get an error

Tags: macos, odoo-10, bitnami

Do anyone known how to revert my mistake? it is normal don't be allowed to save this file?

[this is the file that I can't save it, please see line 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsVqh.png)

I was use the developing mode in Odoo 10 when I editing product.template.product.form file with Formview option, when I miss **<** in my sentence and I saved. I made this syntax mistake in line 21 **field name="x_season"/>** sentence. After that I trying to reedit again and again, stop servers, start server, log in, log out, etc... but when I try to save I can't. Why ????

[TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji9Aq.png)
**Odoo Client Error
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'field.attrs.name')
http://localhost:8080/web/static/src/js/views/list_view.js:381

Comment: Try to do this via original code file or else upgrade base module.

Answer (score 0):

If you made a mistake modifying a view in the developer mode, you only have to restart the Odoo service updating the module which generated the views you modified. I guess in your case you have to update the views of the module `product`. To do that, in console:

```
python /your-odoo-path/odoo-bin -c /your-config-file-path/.odoo.conf -d your-database-name -u product
```

It will restore the XML code and remove the developer mode modifications in `product` module view.

Comment: About /your-config-file-path/ do you mean the full path to go in /odoo/conf folder?

Comment: Yes, in parameter `-c` you have to specify the absolute path to your Odoo configuration file.